# How to get class from "li" like for <select>

Tags: jquery, html-lists

How do you get the class from a li when its inside multiple elements like this?

```
var ChooseAltType = $("<div>").appendTo(field_firstchild);

$('<div id="chooseCustomFields'
  + field_id
  + '" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1"><span>Choose Type</span>'
  + '<ul id="chooseCustomField'
  + field_id
  + '" class="dropdown">'
  + '<li class="chooseCheckbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseAlternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseDropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseTextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>'
  + '</ul></div>').appendTo(field_secondchild).addClass("metro three-d")
.click(function() {
    alert($('#chooseCustomFields' + field_id + ' ul #chooseCustomField'
            + field_id + ' li').prevAll().length);
});
```

It's just a piece of code, but I hope it's enough!

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to do?  Also a well formatted code will help you help better

Comment: I am dynamically creating elements (including the ul-list) which I need to use the class of each li for a "later step".

Comment: will you please fomat question code in readable way

Comment: Looks like you should read the jquery docs http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var ChooseAltType = $("<div>").appendTo(field_firstchild);

$('<div id="chooseCustomFields'
  + field_id
  + '" class="wrapper-customfields" tabindex="1"><span>Choose Type</span>'
  + '<ul id="chooseCustomField'
  + field_id
  + '" class="dropdown">'
  + '<li class="chooseCheckbox"><i class="fa-icon-check"></i>Checkbox</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseAlternatives"><i class="fa-icon-list-ul"></i> Alternatives</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseDropdown"><i class="fa-icon-list-alt"></i> Dropdown</li>'
  + '<li class="chooseTextField"><i class="fa-icon-font"></i> Text</li>'
  + '</ul></div>').appendTo(field_secondchild).addClass("metro three-d")
.click(function() {
    $('#chooseCustomField' + field_id + ' li').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('classs'))
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh! Brilliant! Exactly what I need! Now I just need the get the one that's selected, but thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

well here is what you can do

```
   var class= $("li").attr('class'); // you can use your own Selector instead of $("li")
```